# One DTO for multiple Entities in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I just started with Hibernate and I always wonder if I can create DTO to receive data for multiple Entities and if so, how?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a pretty vagues question. If DTO is a simple `Object` with getter and setter then of course you can create one and manually map them. What is it that you ultimately want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

Blaze-Persitence is a query builder on top of JPA which supports many of the advanced DBMS features on top of the JPA model. I created Entity Views on top of it to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

Here is an example model that involves multiple DTOs

```
@EntityView(User.class)
interface UserProjection {
    Long getId();
    EmployeeFirstNameProjection getEmployee();
}

@EntityView(Employee.class)
interface EmployeeFirstNameProjection {
    String getFirstName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserProjection dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserProjection.class, id);`

But the Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.4/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-features

It will only fetch the mappings that you tell it to fetch